# Keras : ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using `keras.utils.Sequence` as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I wanted to do a simple classification task but when I try to run it, I am getting this error:

```
`ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using `keras.utils.Sequence` as input.`
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: Did it say _"Found 100 images in 2 categories"_ or something?

Comment: Well there's your problem. Keras didn't find the images. The first problem is solved though. Just make sure the images directory is found by Keras.

Comment: This is not your original problem though. That's another one since your original problem is solved.

Comment: you shouldnt. you should mark this one as solved and do your research on why keras didnt find the images. dont change the question after answers have been posted

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine that you want to predict if it's a Dog or a Cat picture, you have two labels Dog and Cat. Now when it comes to CNN dataset the way most of peoples structure it (which is  what is expecting image_generator.flow_from_directory) looks like this :

Train/
.........Cat/
...............Image1.jpg
...............Image2.jpg
.........Dog/
...............Image3.jpg
...............Image4.jpg
Same for your label directory.
Btw your directory Label should be renamed validation ( it's not really important but it makes more sense)

Comment: I tried to explain it better, let me know if it's not clear

Comment: I have no idea what are your labels and you are trying to do exactly, i don't have the time to train your model either. I'm sorry but you will need to give more information on what your problem is after you changed your dataset structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyword `validation_data`. If you pass your validation dataset without the keyword, Keras thinks `validation_dataset` is your labels.

```
model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=validation_dataset, batch_size=32, epochs=1)
```