# ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using `keras.utils.Sequence` as input

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to image processing and machine learning in python. I have been trying to execute a model in google colab using inceptionv3 but i am stuck at fitting the model.

```
    # fit the model
    # Run the cell. It will take some time to execute
    validation_data=test_set
    epochs=10
    steps_per_epoch=len(training_set)
    validation_steps=len(test_set)
    r = model.fit(
    training_set,
    validation_data,
    epochs,
    steps_per_epoch,
    validation_steps
    )
```

the whole code is in my git repository.
https://github.com/Aditya757/MyRepository.git

this is my dataset image link below

```
      https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWaJ8.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write

```
model.fit(
    training_set,
    validation_data=validation_data,
    epochs=epochs,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    validation_steps=validation_steps
)
```

If you pass validation_data without the keyword, it will bind to 'y'

EDIT: also, this was already answered. First result on google [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557091/keras-valueerror-y-argument-is-not-supported-when-using-keras-utils-sequen)...

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked but I am getting further error of graph execution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass feature vector/matrix `X` and ground truth `y` first. The `.fit()` method assumes `validation_data` to be your target/ground truth. Better you specify argument and pass its value.

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data= (X_val, y_val), validation_steps=10, epochs=20, steps_per_epoch=len(X_train), callbacks=[checkpoint,early])
```